# cortexa7 CPU(s) took too long time to execute a loop compared to cortexa15 CPU(s)

Tags: cpu, cortex-a

I am testing CPU performance. I used 02 boards with armv7 and SMP support: cortexa15@1.5GHz dual core and cortexa7@1GHz dual core.

Then, execute a simple loop as below and measure time of execution:

```
#define DEFAULT_CALC_LOOPS 1000
#define LOOPS_MULTIPLIER 4.2
...
loops = DEFAULT_CALC_LOOPS;
...
void *calc(int loops)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < loops * LOOPS_MULTIPLIER; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 125; j++) {
            // Sum of the numbers up to J
            volatile int temp = j * (j + 1) / 2;
            (void)temp;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

The results showed on 02 boards after variety of tests:

- cortexa15: ~1.2 ms
- cortexa7: ~5 ms

There's a big difference between the above results.

Are there any dependence or limitation impacting to the results ? Who experienced with this can share me ideas ? Thanks.

Comment: Seems reasonable, the cortexa15 generally gives 2-3 times the performance of cortexa7 + you have it clocked at 50% more speed.

Comment: First look, I also considered it reasonable. I did another practice - used another board support both a15 and a7 (https://www.iwavesystems.com/rz-g1h-q7-development-kit.html) --> Disabled all a15 and only kept dual core a7 --> I only got ~1.2 ms of execution.

Comment: If you are using GCC you can add `-Ofast -mtune=native` optimization options and check difference once more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, cortexa15 has over 2x - 3x performance compared to cortexa7. Besides, I am having cortexa15@1.5GHz and cortexa7@1GHz.
So I also think the above result is reasonable.

Below, I'll give an example for cortexa15 case study to measure execution time:

1. Formula to calculate CPU time:

   CPU execution time = Instruction count x CPI x Clock cycle

I: Number of Instruction

CPI: cycles per instruction (IPC = 1/CPI)

C: Clock cycle (1/CPU clock) - second

2. Refer community: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instructions_per_second

Take a look to cortexa15 dual-core (same with iWave G1M/N).

Cortexa15 executes 9,900 MIPS at 1.5 GHz, average IPC = 6.6

> CPI = 1/IPC = 1/6.6 = 0.1515 cycle/instruction

3. G1M/N have maximun 1.5 GHz ( range of clock ~1.3 GHz - 1.5 GHz)
   I assume the boards work with best effort (1.5 GHz)

> C = 1/(1.5.10^9) = 0.6667 ns

4. Translate C code to assembly code for ARM arch:

   for (i = 0; i < loops * LOOPS_MULTIPLIER; i++) {

   ```
       for (j = 0; j < 125; j++) {
           // Sum of the numbers up to J
           volatile int temp = j * (j + 1) / 2;
           (void)temp;
       }
   ```

   }

Refer: https://godbolt.org

> I = (((9+9) * 125) + 17) * 1000 * 4.2 = 9521400

The CPU execution time finally is 0.000962 seconds. Approximate **0.962 ms** to execute the loop with the best effort of CPU.

In worst case (at 1.3 GHz), CPU time for the loop is around **1.109 ms**.

Via testing, I got the same values.

--

I do more case for cortexa7@1GHz.

> CPU execution time = 9521400 * 1/1.9 * 1ns = 5.011 (ms)